# Gradle build failed(disposed module)

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build, libgdx

So when I launch my application, the window pops up and the build keeps on running forever even when the application works fine.

But as soon as I terminate my app window, it pops up Gradle build failed error following stack trace

Execution failed for task ':desktop:DesktopLauncher.main()'.

Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1

From terminal it works fine but without run configs I can't run in debug mode and cant use hot swap!

Also in the idea.log file this exception is shown

> java.lang.AssertionError: Already disposed: Module: 'Bunny'
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.lambda$throwAlreadyDisposed$1(ComponentManagerImpl.java:286)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.lambda$run$1(ReadAction.java:53)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:936)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.compute(ReadAction.java:57)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.run(ReadAction.java:53)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.throwAlreadyDisposed(ComponentManagerImpl.java:284)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getPicoContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.java:277)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:182)
>       at com.intellij.facet.FacetManager.getInstance(FacetManager.java:31)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.facet.gradle.GradleFacet.getInstance(GradleFacet.java:57)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.getGradleBuildFile(GradleUtil.java:320)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.issues.SyncIssuesReporter.report(SyncIssuesReporter.java:89)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.issues.SyncIssuesReporter.report(SyncIssuesReporter.java:66)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.issues.SyncIssuesReporter.report(SyncIssuesReporter.java:59)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncResultHandler.setUpProject(SyncResultHandler.java:139)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncResultHandler.onSyncFinished(SyncResultHandler.java:89)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.NewGradleSync.lambda$sync$4(NewGradleSync.java:182)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.util.ExecutionCallback.setExecuted(ExecutionCallback.java:58)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.util.ActionCallback.setDone(ActionCallback.java:72)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncExecutionCallback.setDone(SyncExecutionCallback.java:55)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncExecutor.executeFullSync(SyncExecutor.java:241)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncExecutor.syncProject(SyncExecutor.java:199)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncExecutor.lambda$syncProject$1(SyncExecutor.java:137)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:279)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:248)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncExecutor.syncProject(SyncExecutor.java:142)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.NewGradleSync.sync(NewGradleSync.java:185)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.NewGradleSync.access$000(NewGradleSync.java:59)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.NewGradleSync$2.run(NewGradleSync.java:151)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:894)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:169)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:591)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:537)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:156)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:408)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Comment: Does it help if you run via IntelliJ IDEA instead? https://i.imgur.com/HpeUaUE.png

Comment: What's your build and run delegate setting? See the screenshot in the previous comment.

Comment: That screenshot settings worked like magic! Thanks.
But I am using libgdx project I hope there wont be problems?